# What is the difference between local and centralized web agents?

Tags: single-sign-on, agent, opensso

For the OpenSSO/OpenAM server, two types of Agents exist: J2EE agents and web policy agents. A web agent protects the entire set of resources available on the web server, while J2EE agents only protect resources within a web application hosted on an application server. Both can be configured as a "local" or "centralized" agent. What exactly is the difference between local and centralized web policy agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **centralized** agent configuration, the configuration is stored in OpenSSO/OpenAM server and the agents only contain a reference towards the server.

When using **local** agent configuration, configuration is done through the usage of configuration files stored on the agent machine itself.  This option is for backwards compatibility with older versions.

See [OpenSSO/OpenAM docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19316-01/820-3740/ggqvc/index.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, the difference seems to be the configuration type. For centralized agents, the configuration can be defined through the OpenAM server at "Access Control / realm-name / Agents / agent-name / Advanced", for local agents, the configuration of the agent defined in OpenSSOAgentConfiguration.properties can be changed locally on the host server of the agent, by editing 
the configuration file directly. In both cases, the policies are still handled by the OpenAM instances, but it is possible to make exceptions with the Not-Enforced URL List, which is stored in the configuration.